# Camel issue with JMX Endpoints and injection for SEDA

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jmx, apache-camel

There seems to be an issue with camel and JMX. One of the great features of the SEDA JMX component is the ability to see the queue size using the get queue method which is found under org.apache.camel->endpoints->COMPNAME/camel->"seda://xyz"...

However when using something like

```
@EndpointInject(uri="seda:closeData?concurrentConsumers=50")
ProducerTemplate producerSymbQueue;
//...
producer.sendBody(object)
//...
```

In a POJO it would appear that the SEDA endpoint in JMX disappears and one can no longer see the queue size...

Any ideas on what would be causing this and how to fix?

Comment: Which version of Camel ?

Comment: This has been responded and handled at the Camel mailing list. Camel trunk has a fix to ensure @Produce endpoints get enlisted in JMX as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the annotation only inject the name of the SEDA queue not the options. For example.

```
@EndpointInject(uri="seda:closeData")
ProducerTemplate producerSymbQueue;
```

There is a fix in the Camel trunk to ensure the endpoints get enlisted in JMX as well.

See Camel User Forum for more info.